# why the star projection is required in an is check in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generic-variance

I have this code

```
class Dog<T: Comparable<T>>(private val name: Str, private val weight: T): Comparable<Dog<T>> {
 override fun compareTo(other: Dog<T>): Int {
  return weight.compareTo(other.weight)
 }

 override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
  if (other == null || other !is Dog<*>) return false
  return name == other.name && weight == other.weight
 }
}
```

`*` means `Any?` but `*` is accepted and `Any?` is not. Why is that?

Comment: `*` does not strictly mean `Any?`, it means "some type, don't care what". The `Dog` class needs a generic type parameter of `Comparable`, so it can't be created with just ANY type, therefore referring to `Dog<Any?>` is invalid.

Comment: Also worth pointing out, is that you cannot do `other !is Dog<T>` (on the JVM), because the `T` would be erased at compile time. You therefore have to explicitly say that you don't care about the type parameter with `*`.

Comment: Yes, I know it must be Dog<Comparable<Any?>>, which will be erased at compile time, but what is the secret to this * that makes it unerasable?

Comment: I think it has been already said. `Dog<*>` means we don't care about the type param, we don't check it at all, so it is not a problem it has been erased.

Comment: Ah, I guess I get it now, but please confirm it. Generics are invariant and do not retain subtyping relationships, so `Dog<Number>` is not necessarily a subtype of `Dog<Anything?>` without variance annotations. `*`, on the other hand, is not restricted by this , except for the fact that al its functions can only take `Nothing`.

Comment: Your wording feels strange to me, "generics don't retain subtyping", etc., but generally: yes, by default generics are invariant, so checking for `Dog<Any?>` checks if it's **exactly** `Any?`. `Dog<Number>` is not a subtype of `Dog<Any?>` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. As to the wording, it ís not mine but from a book I read.